$f$ continuous a .e implies $f$ measurable
I was working with one of my friend about this problem and I have said 2 things
$1 \text{ $f$ continuous a e } \rightarrow \exists  N \text{ null set such that }  f\vert_{\mathbb R \setminus N} \text{ is continuous} $
$2$ $\forall A $ open set $f^{-1}(A)=(f^{-1}(A)\cap N) \cup f^{-1}(A)\cap (\mathbb R\setminus N)$  the first one is measurable because subset of a set of null maeasure and the other also because $f^{-1}(A)\cap (\mathbb R\setminus N)= f\vert_{\mathbb R \setminus N}^{-1}(A)$  and $f\vert_{\mathbb R \setminus N} \text{ is continuous}$ so the preimmage will be $U \cap \mathbb (R\setminus N)$   where $U$ is an open set
my friend said no because if a function is continuous a e does not mean it is the restriction of a continuous function I said it is right but now I have said that the restriction is continuous and it's all a different story . There is some mistake ?

This question is answered here: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1780447/65023.  If there are questions, please respond here.  Otherwise, this question can be closed.
